# Powershell unattended interaction with Java Swing GUI

Tags: java, powershell, swing, user-interface, ui-automation

I'm using PowerShell to automate configuration (or re-configuration) of various software packages.

```
$ui=New-Object -ComObject wscript.shell; $kb.Send-Keys "Hello, World!{ENTER}"
```

Some of those packages can be configured via registry or config files or command line interface, and are easy to deal with.

```
gp HKLM:\SOFTWARE\WOW6432Node\Notepad++
```

But others only expose a Java Swing GUI for editing the configurations. In those cases, the cursor may appear at a random location on a dialog, or even on a random tab. I would like to know how set get the focus to a known control by PowerShell without touching the code of the Swing application. The best I've been able to do is to highlight text in a field, copy it to the clipboard, and examine it for clues as to which field it might be, and move around from there.

```
Get-Clipboard
```

That is an awful kludge, which won't work in the general case. Is there a better way to get to a known state on a Java Swing GUI without rewriting it? I don't have source to the Java code to add a keystroke to move the cursor to some home input element and wish I knew of such a keystroke built-into the GUI.

Someone else maintains the Java source code to these applications that are being set up, so I don't have access to it.

Comment: I know about AppActivate, Maybe there should be something similar to find the focus and to set the focus of the control on the app. Then I could find the ID of where the focus is when I manually visit the control, and use a corresponding setter to put it back there via PowerShell script when needed.

Comment: It seems swing must be storing the focus somewhere for it to return to the same tab where it left off the next time the app is launched.  But where?

Comment: I also know about AutoHotKey. It has the ability to examine a rectangle on the screen. I would prefer being able to do it without installing 3rd party tools that might increase attack surface of the PCs.

Comment: Perhaps you can use tools such as procmon, handle, ... to infer the persistence mechanism and location used by the Java app.